# C++/SDL2 Mixer - One ternary works correctly, but a nearly-identical one doesn't?

Tags: c++, sdl-2, conditional-operator

I'm writing some simple test audio code to make sure SDL_mixer works for my application, but in the code to change the volume when given certain characters from std::cin everything works except for subtracting 10 from the volume. Adding 10 works, subtracting 1 works, but subtracting 10 only subtracts 1 and not 10.

In the code below, the variable `sound` is a struct containing 2 maps called `mus` and `eff`, indexed by strings and containing `Mix_Music*` and `Mix_Chunk` variables respectively. "Moon Patrol" is my music audio and "Pew" is my test effect audio. Also, sorry about the big if/else statement, I'm going to be using GLUT keys for input in the actual program.

Relevant Code:

```
Mix_PlayMusic(sound.mus["Moon Patrol"], -1);
    char i = ' ';

    std::cout << "i / k: volume +/- 1 | u / j: volume +/- 10 | q: quit | v: pew sound" << std::endl;

    while (i != 'q')
    {
        std::cin >> i;
        int cVolume = Mix_VolumeMusic(-1);
        if (i == 'i') Mix_VolumeMusic(cVolume + ((1) ? cVolume < 128 : 0));           // +1  Works
        else if (i == 'k') Mix_VolumeMusic(cVolume - (1 ?  cVolume > 0 : 0));         // -1  Works
        else if (i == 'u') Mix_VolumeMusic(cVolume + (10 ? cVolume + 10 <= 128 : 0)); // +10 Works
        else if (i == 'j') Mix_VolumeMusic(cVolume - (10 ? cVolume > 9 : 0));         // -10 Doesn't Work
        else if (i == 'p') std::cout << cVolume << std::endl;                         // Showing Volume Works
        else if (i == 'v') Mix_PlayChannel(-1, sound.eff["Pew"], 0);                  // Effect Works
    }                                                                                 // Exiting works
```

Things I've tried that didn't work:

- Replacing `cVolume` with `Mix_VolumeMusic(-1)` everywhere
- Putting the `10` in parentheses
- Changing the key from `'j'` to `'f'`

Things I've tried that worked as written (but not what I want):

- Changing the `10` to a `1` (code subtracted 1 as told)
- Commenting out the ternary, getting `else if (i == 'j') Mix_VolumeMusic(cVolume - (10));// ? cVolume > 9 : 0));` (subtracts 10 correctly but doesn't protect from negative values)

This shows that it's something about the ternary, but the code for subtracting 1 and subtracting 10 is essentially identical. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Uhhh. The syntax is `condition ? if_true : if_false`. Did you assume it as `if_true ? condition : if_false`?

Comment: Yes I did. I thought that `x ? y : z` meant `x if y otherwise z` and not `if x then y otherwise z`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ternary operator works like this:

variable = (condition) ? expressionTrue : expressionFalse;